# Using if with array and adding additional area

Tags: php

```
 $contactData = array(
        'firstname'             =>  $fname,
        'lastname'              =>  $lname,
    );
```

I fill out my array with the information that I send from my html form with that code. I`m trying to add if so I can add additional information with it like;

```
 $contactData = array(
        'firstname'             =>  $fname,
        'lastname'              =>  $lname,
    );

 if ($i='5') {$contactData = array('what' => 'info');}
```

it probably won't work like this but I don`t know how can I get it working either. Anybody can help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
if ($i=='5') {$contactData['what'] = 'info';}
```

Comment: That's definitly not valid PHP: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: @TimWolla Very much not valid, I have no idea how that slipped through the mental filters, and moreover how this answer got accepted. Fixed. And very red face.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($i == '5') {
    $contactData['what'] = 'info';
}
```